# How to change node id in drupal 7?

Tags: views, nodes

I'm very new to drupal. I'm using drupal 7 with ckeditor. I've created one block with 3 views (Link, Image, Link) in it and I've wrote jQuery on 2 links. Then, I've developed second block with same type of views and wrote same jQuery for 2 links in this new block.

But I found (in FireFox using FireBug addon) that all links have same node id. **views-field-view-node** for 1st link and **views-field-view-node-1** for second link for both blocks. So when I click on 1 block's 1st link, action fires in both blocks because drupal received same link id for another block also.

How can I change/modify this node id of view? So I can give separate action.

Used jQuery:

```
drupal_add_js("jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // change slideshow with your view name
    jQuery('.view-slideshow .view-content').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed:  'fast', 
        timeout: 3000, 
        next:   '.views-field-view-node-1', // problem is here. This id is same for both block's link
        prev:   '.views-field-view-node' 
    });
});", 'inline');
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: could you post the relevant jQuery code and the views out put here

Comment: You dont want to be working with node ids for presentation.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are doing..?

Comment: @SGhosh what part of question you don't understand?

Comment: Sorry, but not much is clear to me..example "one block with 3 views" and "second block with same type of views"

Comment: @SGhosh, refer http://www.unleashed-technologies.com/download/cycleexample/cycle.html as one block. I'm making 3 of these in same page.

Comment: ok...think i got it....added an answer...hope that's helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Drupal related problem.

Your 'next' and 'prev' selectors are not specific enough. You should write also the parent block id.

Every block in a page has a unique id attribute in HTML. You should find stuff like

```
<div id="block-3" class="block">
```

wrapping your slideshow.

Just declare a more specific jQuery selector, adding the block id.

Here's a modification for your code, assuming that the block has a "block-3" id:

```
drupal_add_js("jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // change slideshow with your view name
    jQuery('.view-slideshow .view-content').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed:  'fast', 
        timeout: 3000, 
        next:   '#block-3 .views-field-view-node-1', // added a 'parent child' jquery selector
        prev:   '#block-3 .views-field-view-node' 
    });
});", 'inline');
```

Comment: bingo.. thanks a lot... perfectly solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the link you shared...looks like you need a slideshow.
- You could simply use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) for your purpose.

Hope it helps. If not please do add your comments. I'll try to help if I can. :)